# Embedding a sharepoint side into powerpoint

Tags: powerpoint

is it possible to embed a SharePoint side into PowerPoint. 
We write blogs for the whole company in SharePoint and want to display it in PowerPoint. We tried LiveSlides. It shows the SharePoint side in Poweproint but we can't open the attached files from the blog.

All other solutions like WebViewer are not even showing the webside. I think it is because of .aspx.

Does anyone know a solution how to show SharePoint in PowerPoint?

Regards,

Stevan

[image: SharePoint Side with Blog]

Comment: it is SharePoint Online, On-Premises?  the blogs are the OOTB blogs on SharePoint? You want to display the whole blog or only some page/view?

Comment: it is SharePoint Online. I attached a picture above. We can show the whole page or the blog itself. It does not matther but I think it's easier to show the hole page, isn't it?

Comment: But this screenshot is from SharePoint 2013 isn't it?

Comment: I think so.. I don't Even know.. is there a possibility to check?

Answer (score 0):

I found this third-party free application, should try it and hope it helps. [Link Here.](https://www.ispringsolutions.com/blog/how-to-embed-an-iframe-in-a-powerpoint-presentation/)

Comment: Thank you very much for you help. I will try it as soon I have administration rights.